# Can you create a scroll by using a spell cast from a magical item?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, crafting

In the DMG it says

> The character must also be a spellcaster with spell slots and must be able to cast any spells that the item can produce.

Many magic items let users cast spells. For example Crystal Ball says

> The typical crystal ball, a very rare item, is about 6 inches in diameter. While touching it, you can cast the scrying spell (save DC 17) with it.

It says you can cast the spell. Does that meet the requirements of being able to cast the spell for the purpose of crafting a scroll of that spell?

Comment: Why did the Rules-As-Written tag get removed? I'm fairly certain I understand the intention, but I want to know what the rule book means with a strict reading?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No.**

Jeremy Crawford has clarified that casting a spell from an item is a distinct action than casting the spell yourself.

Eric Wykoff asked:

> Does using a magic item to cast a spell fall under the Use an Object action or Cast a Spell Action?

Jeremy Crawford responded:

> **Neither.** An action is one of those named actions only if it says it is.
>
> My answer was meant just for magic item actions. The DMG clarifies this point and even refers to Fast Hands.

https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/525302987351007235

So taking a second look at the question's quote, emphasis added:

> **The character** must also be a spellcaster with spell slots and **must be able** to cast any spells that the item can produce.

It's not that the character must have **access** to cast the spell. The character must have that **ability**. This jibes with the rest of the sentence, which is all about the character's own spellcasting abilities.

Comment: While I agree with you that's probably the intent I'm not sure your conclusion follows the wording. It doesn't say you must be able to take the cast as spell action. It says you must be able to cast spells the item can produce. It doesn't mention the source...if taken as gospel though Items that grant the actual ability to cast the spell, as opposed to cast the spell through the item would work, ala "The Moon" card from "Deck of Many things" or "Potion of Animal Friendship" correct? Where would that leave things like "Ioun Stone Reserve" or "Ring of Spell Storing"?

Answer (score 4):

Having the magic item to cast the spell gets around the requirement of "*must be able to cast any spells that the item can produce* since you're, you know, casting the spell.

However, the magic item does *not* provide spell slots for you, so you'd need to acquire them some other way; multiclassing and the magic initiate feat being the two most common methods (assuming you don't already have spell slots).

Comment: Magic Initiate does not give spell slots.